# Laravel 5.7 | Pagination - eloquent query (relationship table)

Tags: laravel, pagination

how can I use pagination, where my eloquent query looks:

PageController - method show:

```
$page = Page::where('slug', $slug)->with(['subpages'=>function($q) {
                $q->where('visible', 1)->orderBy('order', 'asc')->paginate(9);
}])->first();
```

I would like to paginate subpages on page's View blade (Page - one to many - Subpage relationship)

Here is part of my show.blade.php view:

```
{{ $page->subpages->links() }}
```

Error:

```
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist.
```

---

EDIT:

FULL FUNCTION SHOW:

```
public function show(PageRepository $pageRepo, $slug){
        $page = Page::where('slug', $slug)->with(['subpages'=>function($q) {
            $q->where('visible', 1)->orderBy('order', 'asc');
        }])->first();
        $subpages = $page->subpages()->paginate(2);
        $sidebar = Navbar::where('type','sidebar')->orderBy('order')->with(['pages'])->get();
        return view('pages.page.show', [
            "page" => $page,
            "subpages" => $subpages,
            "sidebar" => $sidebar,
   ]);
}
```

VIEW:

```
<div class="row display-flex">
    @foreach($page->subpages as $subpage)
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card mb20">
            <div class="card-block">
                <h4 class="card-title font400">{{ $subpage->title }}</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
{{ $subpages->links() }}
```

Comment: from what i can see, you did not define what links is unless it's a method in your model. but yeah, if not it's just something random for laravel to pick up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to paginate the relation from what I see, but you're querying the parent model. That's what's wrong. You have to completely change your logic since the subquery doesn't map the relation inside the Laravel Model. It's just used as a condition to retrieve that model.

You query should look like this:

```php
$page = Page::where('slug', $slug)->with(['subpages'=>function($q) {
    $q->where('visible', 1)->orderBy('order', 'asc') // ->paginate(9); This is not necessary
}])->first();
```

Now that you have the parent model, you can execute a new query for the relation, and there you have to call the `paginate` method:

I don't think that would be a good practice to do something like this in your blade view:

```php
{{ $page->subpages()->paginate(9)->links() }}
```

But it's better to implement a new variable:

```
// Previous code that retrieves the page

$subpages = $page->subpages()->paginate(9);

return response()->view('your.blade.view', compact('page', 'subpages');
```

now you can use the `subpages` variable, that contains the paginated results, in your view

Comment: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::pagiante does not exist.

Comment: Pardon, I've updated my code... I forgot the brackets

Comment: Number of pages in Links() is correct, but on each page I have the same (all) elements.

Comment: Without the full code of your controller and view it's hard to say what's happening...

Comment: Also you can manually set the page retrieving it from the request. Have a look at the [API Reference](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_paginate)

Comment: Ah ok, I changed foreach loop from $page->subpages to $subpages and works :P